# The result prints the amount of items in a list

Tags: python

```
#list
gamesAvailable = ["Minecraft", "League of Legends", "Valorant", "Wild Rift", "Mobile Legends", "Call of Duty", "Pokémon", "Esports King", "Sims", "Mir4"]
print(gamesAvailable, end = ", ")

#input game
gameSelection = input("\nSelect your Game: ")

#for loop
for games in gamesAvailable:
    if gameSelection == "Minecraft":
        print("You have selected", gamesAvailable [0])
    elif gameSelection == "League of Legends":
        print("You have selected", gamesAvailable [1])
```

is there a way where the result can only print one time?

Comment: what do you mean one time? you are looping therefore it will print for each item in the list

Comment: Just print `gameSelection`? It's the game that was selected

Comment: Print what one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the for loop -

```
gamesAvailable = ["Minecraft", "League of Legends", "Valorant", "Wild Rift", "Mobile Legends", "Call of Duty", "Pokémon", "Esports King", "Sims", "Mir4"]
print(gamesAvailable, end = ", ")

#input game
gameSelection = input("\nSelect your Game: ")

if gameSelection == "Minecraft":
   print("You have selected", gamesAvailable [0])
elif gameSelection == "League of Legends":
   print("You have selected", gamesAvailable [1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in range(len(gamesAvailable))
    print(gamesAvailable[x])
```

or

```
print(*gamesAvailable)
```

or with a comma sep

```
print(*gamesAvailable, sep = ', ')
```